# GridLayout has not the desired number of columns and lines

Tags: java

I'm doing a hangman game and have created a GridLayout filled with buttons that has the layout of 3, 12. This is so that I can fill all the panel with the letters of the alphabet, but the GridLayout has a layout of 3, 9 and has left a space with no button. Does the GridLayout have any limitation with this?

```
JPanel botoes = new JPanel();
// ...
botoes.setLayout( new GridLayout(3,12));
new JButton("A");
new JButton("B");
new JButton("C");
new JButton("D");
new JButton("E");
new JButton("F");
new JButton("G");
new JButton("H");
new JButton("I");
new JButton("J");
new JButton("K");
new JButton("L");
new JButton("M");
new JButton("N");
new JButton("O");
new JButton("P");
new JButton("Q");
new JButton("R");
new JButton("S");
new JButton("T");
new JButton("U");
new JButton("V");
new JButton("W");
new JButton("X");
new JButton("Y");
new JButton("Z");
```

### Edit 1

I realized my calculation was wrong

Comment: Why you declare a [3, 12] grid when you need a [3, 9] grid? Try `new GridLayout(3, 9)` please check the [GridLayout documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem comes from 3*12=36. On display, you got 3*9=27, or 26 letters and a blank space. The other columns may not be displayed because they are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `botoes.setLayout( new GridLayout(3,12));` to `botoes.setLayout( new GridLayout(3,9));`, as Valentin Marle wrote in previous comment.